# JSP not showing code insight jdeveloper

Tags: jsp, jdeveloper, code-completion

i am using jDeveloper 11.1.2.
When i was using JDeveloper 11.1.1.3 , my jsp's where showing code insight correctly when i clicked on CTRL+SPACE after writing any methodname etc.
But after upgrading to jdeveloper 11.1.2 my jsps are not showing code insight on ctrl+space , only java file shows properly code insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with the below steps in jdeveloper:
Tools->Preferences->Audit
Ensure Code Assist is checked. Even then if it doesn't works, go to Profiles under Audit and just click on 'Restore Default' button and then press OK. It should work then.